# Javascript's `window.resizeTo` isn't working

Tags: javascript, window-resize, firefox7

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet to do some very specific resizing to do browser size testing, and I can't seem to get the web browser to resize using `window.resizeTo`.

Overly simplified example that doesn't work:

```
javascript:window.resizeTo(1024,600);
```

I can understand that browsers might have disabled this feature, but here's a screenshot of my JavaScript Settings in Firefox:

[image: Advanced JavaScript Settings clearly displaying the "Move or resize existing windows" option as checked]

Am I missing something obvious or should I file a bug report?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=565541), this is a new feature, not a bug. Specifically:

> Two rules:
>
> 1. Can't resize a window/tab that hasn't been created by window.open.
> 2. Can't resize a tab if the tab is in a window with more than one tab.

If I understand this "fix" correctly, you can resize only your own popup windows, not the main window.

Comment: Then why doesn't `var w=window.open("","","width=100,height=100");w.resizeTo(1024,600);` work?

Comment: @zzzzBov: Have Firebug installed? Seems there's a bug which interferes with the browser somehow - see comments [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=565541#c45) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=565541#c47). And according to [this comment](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=565541#c49), a patch is already committed.

Comment: FF took away the ability to use javascript: in the address bar as well, gotta use their Scratchpad. what a pain... window resizing and moving also doesn't work in IE8+. thought I was going mad until I read those "bug" reports.

Comment: I wish they had added some way to specify geometry from the command line before adding this "feature"

Comment: i can't resize the parent window...so I open a smaller window, but this smaller window needs to know about all the other windows that are open.