# Use JavaScript to check if location bar is being displayed (for Internet explorer)

Tags: javascript, debugging, cross-browser, popup

I'm using a function to resize window when a popup is opened. It's supposed to calculate the coordinates of a table and open the popup according to it. (to avoid the popup being too small and needing to use scroll).

The problem is that when I test it in my local environment, it works fine, but when I test it running on another environment, it seems that it's not being applied (but I tested it from the same machine, using the same browser.) Do you have any idea of what could possibly be the problem?
Here's my javascript function who does the resize:

```
function resizeWindowHeightForLittleRows(bottom){
    var tHeader = parseInt(document.getElementById('xtFzRow').style.height) + 
                  parseInt(document.getElementById('headerTable').clientHeight) +
                  28; /*Title Bar*/
    var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
    var isFF = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > -1;
    var titleBarHeight = isChrome ? 40 : (isFF ? 55 : 20); 
    var tableHeight = parseInt(document.getElementById('xtFCInner').style.height) + titleBarHeight;
    var screenHeight = tHeader + tableHeight + bottom;
    var availHeight = screen.availHeight-100;
    window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth-100, screenHeight <= availHeight ? screenHeight : availHeight);

}
```

As I verified the same javascript is being applied in both cases and I tested from the same machine with the sabe browser, I have no idea what configuration (or something else) could be the cause of this issue. Any ideas I can try?

**UPDATE:  The problem is that my function is not considering if url bar is being displayed or not**

I need to add in my resize function the verification if url bar is being displayed, to get the correct values when resizing it

Comment: Different browser versions maybe? Anyways, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641648/the-javascript-resizeto-function-not-working-in-chrome-and-opera and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602078/javascripts-window-resizeto-isnt-working

Comment: it cannot be.. I tested with the same browser.. I just change the url (localhost it works, but in another environment, it doesn't.. and the same javascript code is being applied... it's really weird)

Comment: Same browser doesn't necessarily mean same version. But it's probably not the problem anyways. Did you check your browser console to see if there's any errors?

Comment: yes I did.. I found the problem, but I don't know the solution yet.. I'm not considering the url bar to set the size of popup, and in my local environment, it isn't being displayed, but when I test in another environment, it is.. so this is the problem! I'll edit the question and search for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in FF and Chrome, you can use `window.locationbar` to check if it's visible or not, but this isn't implemented for IE.

My suggestion is to consider adding 30px more to the titlebarheight in your JavaScript function:

```
function resizeWindowHeightForLittleRows(bottom){
    var tHeader = parseInt(document.getElementById('xtFzRow').style.height) + 
              parseInt(document.getElementById('headerTable').clientHeight) +
              28; /*Title Bar*/
    var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
    var isFF = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > -1;
    var titleBarHeight = isChrome ? 40 : (isFF ? 55 : 50);// adding 30px if it's not chrome or FF
    var tableHeight = parseInt(document.getElementById('xtFCInner').style.height) + titleBarHeight;
    var screenHeight = tHeader + tableHeight + bottom;
    var availHeight = screen.availHeight-100;
    window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth-100, screenHeight <= availHeight ? screenHeight : availHeight);
}
```