# Change window width with the Firefox Addon SDK

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to create a addon that resizes the current Firefox window.
I have realized that I should use the `pageMod` to include a `contentScriptFile` to inject a script into the current page. From there I'm trying to do `window.resizeTo(400, 800);` but it does nothing. I can get the `window.innerWidth` so the window object is working. I have also tried firing the `resizeTo` with `self.port.on` but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it could be because of limitation of window.resizeTo()

Please refer to - [Javascript's `window.resizeTo` isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602078/javascripts-window-resizeto-isnt-working).

As mentioned in above link - there are two rules that applies:

```
1) Can't resize a window/tab that hasn't been created by window.open.
2) Can't resize a tab if the tab is in a window with more than one tab.
```

Also, make sure that resizing is enabled in FF by JS (Go to Firefox > Options > Options > Content(Sub-tab) and then click on Advanced Button beside Enable Javascript)