# How to resize windows with help of jquery on change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the width of windows on dropdown change event. But I am stuck on it. The window is not resizing. here is my code:

```
 $(".optionextended-narrow-swap-select select").change(function() {
    $(window).resize(function(){
    // here comes the code for resize. 

     alert (""); // for now it is not event alerting

    });

});
```

Please help me to resize window. I just want to reduce it by 1 px just to trigger some event.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
window.resizeTo(window.innerWidth-1, window.innerHeight);
```

**resizeTo():**
     The resizeTo() method resizes a window to the specified width and height.

**For reducing width by 1 px:** Get current width using`window.innerWidth` and subtract 1 from it.

Comment: Can you explain your code Please that why we understand little about that resizeTo

Comment: Not working. Does Jquery have some function to resize?

Comment: I want it inside the .change function. like when user changes the value from dropdown, then windows resize. how can it be achived

Comment: @user3800660: whoa...take it easy. i was away. in which browser have you tested this??

Comment: @user3800660: also there are some restrictions for this. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7602372/1719752

Comment: Sorry man just frustated at the bug u know. its firefox. is there any way that i can use jquery function to resize?

Comment: @user3800660: have you seen the restriction for this??

Answer (score 0):

you need to trigger the window resize event.

Check the below article.

[How to trigger the window resize event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818474/how-to-trigger-the-window-resize-event-in-javascript)

Comment: No i need to resize the window. the link you send triggers an event after resize

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$(".optionextended-narrow-swap-select select").change(function() {
$(window).trigger( "resize" );
});
```

This was demo How it works

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z2DRM/)