# Window.resizeTo not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am trying to call `window.resizeTo` but it is not working. I read somewhere that `window.resizeTo` will not work until `window.open` is called. Can I resize the window without calling `window.open` using jQuery?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo#Notes

Comment: Check this linked post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602078/javascripts-window-resizeto-isnt-working

Answer (score 3):

As you say, you cannot resize windows which you didn't create using `window.open`. It is not possible in modern browsers, whether you use jQuery or not.